# Labeled constants in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have several lemmas in which I specify constants $C_1$, $C_2$, and so forth for later reference.  Naturally, this is annoying when I later insert a new constant definition in the middle.  What I'd like is a macro that lets me assign labels to constants and handles the numbering for me.  I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
%% Pseudocode
\begin{lemma}
    \newconstant{important-bound}
    We will show that $f(x) \le \ref{important-bound} g(x)$ for all $x$.
\end{lemma}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is `important-bound` referring to?  Is it the number of the lemma, for example?

Comment: I believe he would like to *define* `important-bound` with command `\newconstant` as the 'next' C_i, and be able to `\ref` to it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, thank you finrod.  And maybe `\newconstant` should take a parameter that lets you specify the base symbol (so you can have C_i or c_i or whathaveyou).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on rcollyer's suggestions of using a counter:

```
%counter of current constant number:    
  \newcounter{constant} 
%defines a new constant, but does not typeset anything:
  \newcommand{\newconstant}[1]{\refstepcounter{constant}\label{#1}} 
%typesets named constant:
  \newcommand{\useconstant}[1]{C_{\ref{#1}}}
```

(This code was edited to allow labels longer than one character)

And here is a code snippet that seems to work:

```
I want to define two constants:\newconstant{A}\newconstant{B}$\useconstant{A}$ and
$\useconstant{B}$. Then I want to use $\useconstant{A}$ again.
```

Comment: Very nice. I thought about something like this, but wasn't sure if labels would work as intended. Definitely +1.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to create your own [counter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Topics).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Aniko's answer, I used 
[this layered macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/variable-name-newcommand-with-parameters-within-another-newcommand)  so that it created a shorthand for the label,

```
\newcounter{constant}
\newcommand{\newconstant}[1]{\refstepcounter{constant}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\useconstant}[1]{C_{\ref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\defconstant}[1]{ \newconstant{c_#1}\expandafter\newcommand\csname c#1\endcsname{\useconstant{c_#1}} }  %
```

So to use this, you would then do

```
\defconstant{a}
\defconstant{b}
There exist constant $\ca$ and $\cb$ such that ....
```

careful not to overwrite existing commands (i'm sure it would warn you anyhow)

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/constants   also seems to have something similar. The ubuntu package  texlive-latex-extra  includes this one too.